# Handling exception with BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, .net, exception, backgroundworker

In a WinForms application, an exception is occurring within a method that is run when a `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event is fired.

```
System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker worker = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
worker.DoWork += import_begin;
System.Objects arguments = new System.Object[] {filename, why};
worker.RunWorkerAsync(arguments);

private void import_begin(System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    // unpack the arguments
    System.String filename = (System.String)arguments[0];

    // exception is occurring here
    Controller.Excel excel = new Controller.Excel(filename);
}
```

I have set breakpoints to pin down where the exception was thrown, and it was in the line of code as commented above. Even after handling the exception, there is a dialog box that shows up:

> "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation".
>   [image]

Is it possible to prevent this dialog box?

By the way, the exception is of type `InvalidDataException`, due to an invalid file type attempted to be imported.

**Edit:** partial `Controller.Excel` code:

```
class Excel
{
    protected OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage excel;
        protected const int HEADER_ROW_OFFSET = 7;
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo provider;

        // ctor
        public Excel(System.String filename)
        {

            excel = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(filename));
            excel.Compatibility.IsWorksheets1Based = false;
            provider = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        }
}
```

Comment: Well you can nest the _body_ of `import_begin` in a `try-catch` (or maybe just the `new Controller.Excel` line) however its probably not getting to the cause of the exception.  If you know you are getting an _"invalid file type"_ error, what is the value of `filename`?  Is is actually pointing to an Excel file path?  Is it a valid Excel file? Have you tried opening the file directly in Excel?

Comment: @MickyD, ok I will post that code.

Comment: @MickyD it is using the standard file dialog form. It is intended for the user to open an .xlsx file, and this exception occurs whenever they try to open any other file type.

Comment: @MickyD I think it's this line: `excel = new OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage(new System.IO.FileInfo(filename));` it's in the constructor.

Comment: I see now, you just want to handle the condition when the user somehow picks a file which isn't an Excel file and/or corrupt.

Comment: Yes, exactly. It seems the constructor expects an .xlsx file. If it isn't, then the `InvalidDataException` occurs. But I don't want that dialog showing up that I mentioned.

Comment: There is a try/catch somewhere in the code.  The stack trace is crucial to find it back.  With the message box showing, use Debug > Break All.  Then Debug > Windows > Threads to select the worker thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OP:

> it is using the standard file dialog form. It is intended for the user to open an .xlsx file, and this exception occurs whenever they try to open **any other file type**

I sounds as though you just want to handle the condition gracefully when the user somehow picks a file which isn't an Excel file and/or corrupt.

Change your code to something like:

```
private void import_begin(System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs args)
{
    // unpack the arguments
    System.String filename = (System.String)arguments[0];

    // you probably should inspect the file extension in `filename` to see if it
    // is at least .xls or .xlsx prior to using Controller

    try
    {   
        Controller.Excel excel = new Controller.Excel(filename);
        ...        
    }
    catch (InvalidDataException ex)
    {
        // gracefully handle the error
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // eat, don't want thread to unwind
    }
}
```

Now if they pick any other file type or the file is a corrupted Excel file, the `catch` handler above will be invoked where you can handle the situation gracefully.

Normally you shouldn't update the UI from a worker but `MessageBox` has it's own message pump.

### Tip

To keep it neat, you might want to inspect the file's extension prior to running the `BackgroundWorker`.  It's a quick check for a quick win and keeps all UI-related activities in the main thread and not a child thread where things become more complex.

Comment: I tried something like that. The message box will show up, followed by one with "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation", which I don't want.

Comment: so this code is inside an event handler for an "import" button. I tried wrapping everything inside that event handler with a `try`/`catch`, in hopes of catching it there, but it still shows up.

Comment: @Al2110 does it only occur when the user picks a non-Excel file **and** you are running it in the debugger?

Comment: @Al2110 try the update with the extra `catch (Exception ex)`

Comment: @Al2110 when you run it directly from Windows Explorer?  Don't run from VS

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207814/discussion-between-mickyd-and-al2110).

Comment: The "begin_import" is a background worker thread, so you shouldn't call any UI elements such as "MessageBox.Show".  This should be handled in the background worker completed method (which OP does not have in original code), as this runs on the UI thread.

Comment: @jason.kaisersmith I already made a disclaimer for that and more in the answer as well as suggest better practices.